# AnimationController repeat with curve animation

Tags: flutter, animation, curve

How do I make a AnimatedController that repeats, but starts up with a curve animation.

---

### Code:

> AnimationController :

```
var _animating = false;

  AnimationController _rotationAnimationController;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _rotationAnimationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 4 * pi ).animate(_rotationAnimationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _rotationAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

> Button :

```
GestureDetector(
                       onTap: () {
                         Duration startStopTime = Duration(seconds: 3);
                         if(_animating) {
                           _rotationAnimationController.animateBack(1, duration: startStopTime, curve: Curves.easeOut);
                           setState(() {});
                         } else {
                           _rotationAnimationController.repeat() //This needs to start with a curve
                         }
                         setState(() {
                           _animating = !_animating;
                         });
                       },
                       child: [...]
                     ),
```

If you could also make it so that when the *repeat* stops, it does that with a curve, that would be amazing too :)

Thanks for the help allready :D

Comment: *"If you could also make it so that when the repeat stops, it does that with a curve, that would be amazing too :)"* so if you dont want to use a custom `Simulation` then try something like that: `ctrl.value = 0.0;
var controlPoints = [
Offset(0.1, 0.02),
Offset(0.2, 0.1),
Offset(0.8, 0.9),
Offset(0.9, 0.98),
];
var curve = CatmullRomCurve(controlPoints);
ctrl.animateTo(10.0, curve: curve, duration: Duration(seconds: 5));` - you can make some experiments with `controlPoints` to match your needs, the widget to animate is ordinary `RotationTransition(turns: ctrl, child:  ...)`

Comment: @pskink well, it worked fine, but the second time the animateTo just didn't ever run. But I have got an answer now, I marked it with the green mark below.

Comment: you can run it multiple times, this why `ctrl.value = 0.0;` is called first, followed by `ctrl.animateTo(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I understood your question , you want a `CurvedAnimation` right ? This means your animation will repeat but follow a specific curve . So here the best I could do for you :

Define your `AnimationController` like this :

```
 Animation<double> _animation;
 AnimationController _animationController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    final Animation curve =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);

    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi * 4).animate(curve);
  }
```

and your `GestureDetector` like this :

```
     GestureDetector(
                   onTap: () {
                        if (_animationController.isAnimating) 
  {
   _animationController.animateBack(0,duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  } 

  else {
      _animationController.repeat();
    }
  },
                       child: [...]
                     ),
```

**Edit** :

I used a `TweenAnimationBuilder` to have the effect you want :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class TweenAnimatedBuilderRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  TweenAnimatedBuilderRotate({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TweenAnimatedBuilderRotateState createState() =>
      TweenAnimatedBuilderRotateState();
}

class TweenAnimatedBuilderRotateState
    extends State<TweenAnimatedBuilderRotate> {
  double _newAngle = 0;
  Curve curveThatChanges = Curves.easeIn;
  bool isAnimating = false;
  int _millsecs = 2000;
  

  void onCompletion() {
    if (isAnimating) {
      _newAngle += 4 * math.pi;
      curveThatChanges = Curves.linear;
      _millsecs = 1000;

      setState(() {});
    } else {
      _newAngle = 0;
      _millsecs = 2000;
    }
  }

  void onContainerTap() {
    if (isAnimating) {
      isAnimating = false;
      _newAngle = _newAngle;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      curveThatChanges = Curves.easeIn;
      _newAngle += 4 * math.pi;
      isAnimating = true;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: _newAngle),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: _millsecs),
        onEnd: () => onCompletion(),
        curve: curveThatChanges,
        builder: (
          BuildContext ctx,
          double angle,
          Widget child,
        ) {
          _newAngle = angle;
          return Center(
            child: Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateZ(_newAngle),
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                ),
                onTap: () => onContainerTap(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

You can refer to [this](https://medium.com/flutter/custom-implicit-animations-in-flutter-with-tweenanimationbuilder-c76540b47185) Medium article to understand about how `TweenAnimationdBuilder` Works. You can also modify `_millsecs` variable to speed up/down the animation. Pass `TweenAnimatedBuilderRotate()` in the `body` parameter of the `Scaffold(...)`.

Comment: Is my answer , answered your question ?

Comment: Yea, i think. Imma get back in a couple of hours, not currently in a situation to try it. But looks promising

Comment: Jusk checked out the code. And I think I wasn't quite clear about the animation I was looking for; I want it to start with a curve (easeIn) and then after it has reached top speed, stay on that speed, untill it's clicked again. What your code does is it loops the curve animation, so every 2 seconds it starts over again.

Comment: I have edited my answer to have the effect you described in your previous comment. I know it is not the perfect answer , but is all I can do for now. I might work on this problem in future to provide a better answer.

Comment: Dude thanks a bounch :) I had to change one thing, that was so it also had a a end animation, but other than that, amazing work, thansk again :)

Comment: I enjoyed the process